# Recognize multiple symbols in a image without segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to recognize some symbols in a picture, however the background makes it impossible (or at least extremely hard) to segment them using image processing. I have a few hundred thousand labelled samples. The number of symbols in the image is fixed. I tried to create a Dense layer for each symbol in the image and train on the whole images, however that yielded a very disappointing accuracy. What else can I try?

Comment: Can you provide a few sample images?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a specific type of network known as U-Net. It is designed specifically for Image Segmentation. Although it may be difficult to due to the background, a sufficiently complex U-Net could be capable of solving your problem given enough computational resources. See this github's notebook and the cited paper within it.

https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/UNet-Segmentation-in-Keras-TensorFlow/blob/master/unet-segmentation.ipynb